# Opencv - approximate contour to polygon with a defined amount of corners

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, polygon

**What am I doing**: I'm trying to take the photo of a document(**A4 page**) and extract just the document portion and then warp it to look nice and tidy.

**How am I doing it**: So far, I'm finding the contours, and most likely the biggest contour will be the actual document. 
I am then taking that and crop the bounding rectangle, but this is pretty bad if i want to warp it afterwards, because I don't have the actual corners of the document.

So, the challenge right now is: **How do I find a 4 corners poly that fits my document contour.**

So this are the contours in the image:
[image]

And this is what I am trying to detect: **a 4 corners polygon that matches the document contour** (highlighted a poly):

[image]

How to achieve this? 
Is there any better way to approach this challenge?

Comment: What do you get if you take the bounding box if the largest contour?

Comment: @AmitayNachmani I get a rectangle that's very close to the contour, but that does not help with the warping. in order to warp it correctly i need the corners of the actual document

Comment: After you have the bounding box that is very close to the actual location of the corner of the document try runing corner detection on each area around the corner of the bounding box which is close the the actual corner and look for the point with the biggest corener response in each area.

Comment: hough transform...